# AppStudioPlugin.DeveloperPortalAPIFailed after upgrading Teams Toolkit to 4.2.0

Tags: microsoft-teams, vscode-extensions, teams-toolkit

After upgrading Teams Toolkit to 4.2.0, while debugging team Application in Visual studio code, it fails with

API call to Developer Portal failed: Error, Request failed with status code 403, API name: create-app, X-Correlation-ID: undefined. This may come from some intermittent service error. Please wait for a few minutes and retry the current step. data: "<%3Fxml version="<REDACTED: user-file-path>" encoding="<REDACTED: user-file-path>"%3F>\nAuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the <REDACTED: user-file-path>:<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2022-12-21T17:17:27.0783537ZAuthentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version."

stack:
DeveloperPortalAPIFailed: API call to Developer Portal failed: Error, Request failed with status code 403, API name: create-app, X-Correlation-ID: undefined. This may come from some intermittent service error. Please wait for a few minutes and retry the current step. data: "<%3Fxml version="<REDACTED: user-file-path>" encoding="<REDACTED: user-file-path>"%3F>\nAuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the <REDACTED: user-file-path>:<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2022-12-21T17:17:27.0783537ZAuthentication scheme Bearer is not supported in this version."
at AppStudioResultFactory.SystemError (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7338905)
at wrapException (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7304721)
at Object.importApp (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7308431)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:<REDACTED: user-file-path>:96:5)
at async Object.createTeamsApp (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7286749)
at async AppManifest.provision (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7258303)
at async AppManifest. (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:6625833)
at async TeamsfxCore.provision (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:6128194)
at async TeamsfxCore. (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:6625833)
at async FxCore.provisionResourcesOld (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7628193)
at async FxCore. (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7772838)
at async exports.ProjectSettingsWriterMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7846344)
at async exports.ContextInjectorMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7761355)
at async FxCore. (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7768296)
at async exports.VideoFilterAppBlockerMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7896895)
at async exports.ProjectSettingsLoaderMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7844791)
at async exports.ProjectVersionCheckerMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7849870)
at async exports.AadManifestMigrationMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7740883)
at async exports.ProjectConsolidateMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7761067)
at async exports.ProjectMigratorMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7810098)
at async exports.ConcurrentLockerMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7743579)
at async exports.ErrorHandlerMW (<REDACTED: user-file-path>:2:7774291)

While debugging teams app in visual studio code, it should load the application in Microsoft Teams. Instead it is failing. This is after upgrading Team Toolkit to v4.2.0

Comment: Downgrading Teams Toolkit to V4.1.3 works

Comment: Thanks for the update that it worked on downgrading.

Comment: The issue is with V4.2.0. It was confirmed by github https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/7313